# Compare an array with 0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was going through my company's code base and found a statement that compares an array with 0 like this:

array > 0;

if we let array = ["1"], which has a single element, the above statement would be true;
but if let array = ["1", "2"] or [], the statement would become false;

Can someone explain the meaning of this statement, why it yields such results, and if it would be useful in any situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `>`, the engine will first [convert both sides to a primitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan), which will call the `valueOf`, and, if that didn't return a primitive, then the `toString` method if it exists. For arrays, only the `toString` method returns a primitive, so that's what's used - and what it does is equivalent to doing `.join(',')`.

```js
console.log(['1', '2'].toString());
```

[Looking at the spec again](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan), after the array has been turned into a primitive, we now have one side that's a string (which came from the array), and another side that's a number. So, both sides are then converted to numbers:

```
d. Let nx be ? ToNumeric(px).
e. Let ny be ? ToNumeric(py).
```

And then the numbers are compared.

In the case of `['1']`, you get `1 > 0`, which is true.

In the case of `['1', '2']`, the resulting string is `'1,2'`, which cannot be converted into a number, so the following runs:

```
h. If nx or ny is NaN, return undefined.
```

and when `undefined` is returned by this algorithm, the whole `>` evaluates [to `false`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

> and if it would be useful in any situation?

For clean, understandable code, it generally wouldn't. Better to explicitly cast to types whose comparison makes intuitive sense first.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing the array to a number, JavaScript will cast it to a number. You can manually do this by doing `Number(value)`. From my testing it seems like it just tries to cast the first value to a number. However, if there are multiple indexes, it returns `NaN`. And if there are no values it returns `0`.

There's really not much use for the condition as far as I can imagine. It's hard to tell exactly what it's meant to do without context, but my guess is that it's a weird attempt to handle some edge case.